# xpath: how to locate a node that contains more than 1 of another specific node

Tags: xpath, nodes, counting

Using xpath, I want to return all **section** tags that contain more than one **title** tag.  I've tried

```
count(concept/conbody/section:child:title>1)
```

and that didn't return the results.  I want to run this xpath accross many files to locate those < concepts that have section containing more than one title.

```
<concept>
<title>Topic Title</title>
<shortdesc>Short description text.</shortdesc>
<conbody>

<section>
<title>Section Title</title>
<p>paragraph text.</p>
</section>

<section>
<title>Section Title</title>
<p>paragraph text.</p>
<title>Section Title</title>
<p>paragraph text.</p>

</section>

</conbody>
</concept>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending oo how "fix" the ancestors of section arr you may use_

```
concept/conbody/section[count(title) >1]
```

or:

```
//section[count(title) >1]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked well.  Using Find/Replace in files, I had to find the text string <title> in addition to the xpath to return section with greater than one title element.

Answer (score 2):

Query for section with have a second title element, that saves you from retrieving all which is required for counting them:

```
concept/conbody/section[title[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
concept/section[count(title)>1]
```